# Create local self sign certificate windows 11

Tags: certificate, windows-11, self-signed-certificate

Could someone please translate this

```
makecert -n "CN=TempCA" -r -sv TempCA.pvk TempCA.cer

makecert -sr LocalMachine -ss My -a sha1 -n CN=MyTestCert -sky exchange -pe -ic TempCA.cer -iv TempCA.pvk
```

to the new way of creating a self signed certificate on a windows 11 machine?